# Deal with verification email

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, gwt

I'm about to create application with user registration on GWT platfom with also jQuery. One of the key functionality is user registration with it's email checking (my client require such behaviour)

HOWTO: System sends email to the client and client enter to the link and link opens a tab on default browser and information "congrats" popups. As typical, nothing special.

**QUESTION:** As you know GWT is one servlet side. So how you deal with that? I would rather avoid situation where client have open two or more tabs with the same application ...

PS: I'm wondering whether GWT, jQuery or Browser has some deep functionality which could recognize tab in browser via some ID and if tab exists just make it active/visible or in other case open a new one. Or might you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you can't reference a browser tab from a link in an e-mail or even talk from one browser tab to another directly (via cookies maybe? but I'm not sure if updating a cookie in one browser window gives a running script in another window access to the updated data).

If you want to avoid the second application instance, you could have the link be to a page or part in your app that is only intended for telling the server that adress is confirmed. Then you could emmediatly close this window in javascript with `window.close`.  I tried this though and IE gave me a warning that the window was trying to close so the user will still be aware of the second window/tab. Ideally you would show a 'thanks for verifying' message or something similar on the verify url

Concerning updating the first application window:
Maybe you could setup something with a socket that gets an update from the server when the link is clicked

Or you could try the cookie thing I mentioned earlyer, but haven't tested